# MongoDB.Driver C# Cannot deserialize collection with Array of ObjectId

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I am trying to use for the first time MongoDb (in 5 years of programming I always used relational DB) with a .Net Core WebApplication.

I build some Collections using the Atlas free cluster service.
Here is the JSON schema for Tests collection:

```
{
  "title": "Test",
  "properties": {
    "Questions": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "objectId"
      }
    },
    "_id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "description": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "name": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

I created the corresponding model:

```
    namespace DatabaseConnector.Models
    {
        public class Test
        {

        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Questions")]
        public List<string> Questions { get; set; } = null!;

    }
  }
```

But the deserialization does not work:

```
 namespace DatabaseConnector
    {
        public class MongoDBService
        {
    
            private readonly IMongoCollection<Test> _testCollection;
    
            public MongoDBService(IOptions<MongoDBSettings> mongoDBSettings)
            {
                MongoClient client = new MongoClient(mongoDBSettings.Value.ConnectionURI);
                IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase(mongoDBSettings.Value.DatabaseName);
                _testCollection = database.GetCollection<Test>("Tests");
            }
    
            public async Task<List<Test>> GetTestsAsync()
            {
           // here is the raise of the Exception: AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred while deserializing the Questions property of class DatabaseConnector.Models.Test: Cannot deserialize a 'String' from BsonType 'ObjectId'.)
                return await _testCollection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

The Error is:

```
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred while deserializing the Questions property of class DatabaseConnector.Models.Test: Cannot deserialize a 'String' from BsonType 'ObjectId'.)
```

I am not sure how to manage the deserialization of the array if ObjectId, and I also searching for a while through documentation and different samples.
Someone says that it is necessary to implement a specific Serialize/Deserialize methods for some cases. It is true?

To me it seems a not so complicated situation; so I hope there is a simple solution for it.

Thanks in advance for your answers and for some useful material on MongoDb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BSON type in your MongoDB schema and the C# property type in your Test model for the "Questions" field aren't match.

You should change your model as below :

```
public class Test
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        
        [BsonElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        [BsonElement("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        
        [BsonElement("Questions")]
        public List<ObjectId> Questions { get; set; } = new List<ObjectId>();
    }
```